# How to sort List of custom type in android

Tags: java, android, list, sorting

I have custom type WifiList:

```
public class WifiList {
   String mac;
   int level;
}
```

And List of this data type. I want to sort this list descending by level. I have no idea how to do that.

Can you help me?

Comment: Implement `Comparable<WifiLst>` interface and sort it with `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: Read about `Collection.sort` and `Comparator` interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WifiList wifiList = new WifiList();
        wifiList.level = 1;
        WifiList wifiList2 = new WifiList();
        wifiList2.level = 2;
        List<WifiList> asList = Arrays.asList( wifiList, wifiList2 );
        Collections.sort( asList, new Comparator<WifiList>(){

            @Override
            public int compare( WifiList o1, WifiList o2 ){
                if( o1.level > o2.level ){ return -1; }
                if( o1.level == o2.level ){
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    return 1;
                }

            }
        } );

        System.out.println( asList );
```

In other words, if you use a custom comparator you can sort anything. For ascending order just change -1 with 1 and vice versa.